# Fetching a specific range of numeric value from huge list of numbers using AWK

Tags: awk, rhel, nawk

i want to take out certain range of huge numeric values, 720000002774991000 to 720000002774991099. so i tried the below command,

```
awk -F, ' { if (($1 >= 720000002774991000) && ($1 <= 720000002774991099)) print $0} ' VOUCHER_DUMP_REPORT.csv | head
```

VOUCHER_DUMP_REPORT.csv is my input file and has only one column of that huge numbers.

but the output i am getting is not accurate, it has some values other than the range i gave.

output :

```
720000002774991065
720000002774991082
720000002774990985
720000002774991131
720000002774990919
720000002774991110
720000002774990947
720000002774991070
720000002774991042
720000002774991044
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your numbers are too long to be correctly represented as integers.

You have a couple of possible solutions. With GNU awk, you can use `-M` to enable support for [arbitrary precision integers](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arbitrary-Precision-Integers.html):

```
awk -M '$1 >= 720000002774991000 && $1 <= 720000002774991099' file
```

Otherwise, if you're sure that the first column only contains numbers, you can use a string comparison:

```
awk -F, -v min=720000002774991000 -v max=720000002774991099 '
  BEGIN { lmin = length(min); lmax = length(max) } # save length of min and max
  "" $1 < min || "" $1 > max { next }            # skip lines which fail string comparison
  { l1 = length($1) }                            # calculate length of field
  l1 >= lmin && l1 <= lmax                       # check that string length is correct
' file
```

`"" $1` concatenates an empty string with the contents of the first field, which forces awk to treat it as a string rather than a number. Without this, the comparison would be numerical, rather than lexical, and you would have the same problem as in your original attempt.

A probably less efficient but possibly easier to understand version that uses string comparison would be:

```
awk -F, -v min=720000002774991000 -v max=720000002774991099 '
  "" $1 >= min && "" $1 <= max \
  && length($1) >= length(min) && length($1) <= length(max)' file
```

As in the previous version, lines are printed that pass both the string comparison and the length comparison. The downside to this approach is that the length of `min`, `max` and `$1` are calculated more times than necessary.

---

#### Testing (all three of the above approaches)

```
$ cat file
720000002774991065
720000002774991082
720000002774990985
720000002774991131
720000002774990919
720000002774991110
720000002774990947
720000002774991070
720000002774991042
720000002774991044
$ awk -M '$1 >= 720000002774991000 && $1 <= 720000002774991099' file
720000002774991065
720000002774991082
720000002774991070
720000002774991042
720000002774991044
$ awk -F, -v min=720000002774991000 -v max=720000002774991099 '
  BEGIN { lmin = length(min); lmax = length(max) } # save length of min and max
  "" $1 < min || "" $1 > max { next }            # skip lines which fail string comparison
  { l1 = length($1) }                            # calculate length of field
  l1 >= lmin && l1 <= lmax                       # check that string length is correct
' file
720000002774991065
720000002774991082
720000002774991070
720000002774991042
720000002774991044
$ awk -F, -v min=720000002774991000 -v max=720000002774991099 '
  "" $1 >= min && "" $1 <= max \
  && length($1) >= length(min) && length($1) <= length(max)' file
720000002774991065
720000002774991082
720000002774991070
720000002774991042
720000002774991044
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Let me try and get back.

Comment: above commands not working, my objective is that in the output i should not get 720000002774990985 , 720000002774990919 , 720000002774990947.
Here these serials are having same length but out of the range i gave.

Comment: @ramki_ramakrishnan I have tested each approach and edited to show the output - as you can see, each option filters out 5 of the lines in your input.

Comment: thank you, seems its working but i dont understand the code. why was "" used?

Comment: @ramki_ramakrishnan I edited to add an explanation about that.

Comment: Thanks a Lot. it work just fine. and i understood the logic.